# windows hosts file seems modified localhosts xampp

Tags: windows, xampp, localhost, hosts

upon running Comodo Cleaning Essentials found Modified Hosts Threat Warning, checked file in WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc and to my surprise three undefined characters were added after localhost:

http://i60.tinypic.com/2d1s6wz.jpg

(see image), are these just unnecessary spaces or what could have generated this change in hosts file?

I should add that i've been running XAMPP on localhost with no problems connecting though, is it safe to remove these characters? and will XAMPP continue to perform as expected? or should this be error be reported to Comodo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use ip address like `http://127.0.0.1/` or your lan ip adres

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, i have never seen <!--http://127.0.0.1/-->in hosts file, just 127.0.0.1 localhost, or 127.0.0.1 site, do you mean can i connect through IP instead of localhost? The answer would be Yes, that's how i'm connecting to server and mysql using php, using ip instead of localhost, so there seems to be no problem there, i get no errors trying to connect, although the path in DreamWeaver site config is set to localhost for XAMPP configuration. I can run the page and scripts from http://127.0.0.1/mysite with no errors, thanks so much for your help!